# User Wise TIME ZONE possible in Linux Red HAT

Tags: linux, time, rhel

Any possibility to changes user wise time zone in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Which user (a web client, or someone remotely logged thru `ssh`)? He could set the `TZ` environment variable, perhaps by adding a line like

```
export TZ='Europe/Paris'
```

in his `~/.bashrc` file if `bash` is his login shell.

See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [tzselect(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tzselect.8.html)